# locking JTextField from external updates while editing

Tags: java, swing

My GUI displays the data coming from the backend every 500ms. I'm having a race condition when it comes to editing fields. By the time the Action listener is invoked, the value from the backend overwrites whatever the user entered manually into a text field.

Is there a way to lock the field or use a semaphore or retrieve new value from elsewhere?

Thanks.

```
        JTextField tf = new JTextField();
        tf.setName("reg_r"+i);          
        tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();

                //prints OLD value!
                System.err.println(tf.getText());

            }
        });
```

Comment: You want to lock updates coming from the backend or from user?

Comment: So you have a JTextField that the user can update but that also updates automatically every 1/2 second?  Maybe it's me, but that sounds like a very strange design and I'd have to question why you want it to work like this.  Perhaps you want a design fix rather than a code fix.

Comment: @hovercraft OK, if there is a way to bind an object property/field to the textfield, im listening ;) that would be the "design" fix you're talking about

Comment: I wonder if you should have two distinct views, one for data display and another for data entry.

Comment: We would need more info to suggest that.  It does seem odd to have an interface where you're trying to modify a consistently changing value.  Particularly if the value you're updating **to** should be influenced by the most recent value on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i came up with is to detect when the text field is being edited and not update it.

```
JTextField tf = (JTextField) FrameUtils
                    .getComponentById(
                            instance.getContentPane(), "reg_r"
                                    + i);
            Component c = (Component) getFocusOwner();
            if (c == null || !tf.getName().equals(c.getName())) {
            // JTextField is not focused/being edited, proceed with update
            tf.setText(...);
            }
```

Comment: and what if the user kind of "parks" the focus in the textField? No updating will happen ... as others already stated more than once: you need a more complex design ;-)